# Jekyll Pagination Path for img assets

Tags: pagination, jekyll, jekyll-paginator

I followed this [tutorial](https://chrisphillips-cminion.github.io/jekyll/2019/06/26/JekyllPagination.html) for adding pagination to my blog site. For the most part it worked except all the thumbnail/preview images for the blog posts are no longer found because the path is now `http://myblog.com/page2/` or page 3, etc. and my assets path in the front matter is:

```
---
layout: post
title:  "My first blog post"
image: assets/img/post_image.png
```

so i keep receiving:
`` ERROR `/page2/assets/img/post_image.png' not found. ``

How can  i resolve this? Only the images on the first page of the site are found properly because there's no new path.

Answer (score 0):

Just needed to make the image path a relative path like
`/assets/img/post_image.png` and it was fixed.